# Help analysing assembly code 

Tags: assembly, input, x86

I was given a program called `bomb`. When the program runs, it asks for user input (could be string or int). If the user enters wrong input, it will explode.

In order to "defuse" the bomb, i have to analyze the assembly code so that i can enter the correct input.

The program consist of 6 phases, I have done 4 phases but I cant get this fifth one.

As I mentioned, the program reads input from user. What input do I need to enter for this phase, so that I can avoid calling the explode_bomb function, and how to get the answer?

```
08048db0 <phase_5>:
 8048db0:   55                      push   %ebp
 8048db1:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 8048db3:   57                      push   %edi
 8048db4:   56                      push   %esi
 8048db5:   53                      push   %ebx
 8048db6:   83 ec 1c                sub    $0x1c,%esp
 8048db9:   8b 5d 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%ebx
 8048dbc:   89 1c 24                mov    %ebx,(%esp)
 8048dbf:   e8 8c 01 00 00          call   8048f50 <string_length>
 8048dc4:   83 f8 06                cmp    $0x6,%eax
 8048dc7:   74 05                   je     8048dce <phase_5+0x1e>
 8048dc9:   e8 c3 02 00 00          call   8049091 <explode_bomb>
 8048dce:   ba 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%edx
 8048dd3:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 8048dd8:   b9 80 a1 04 08          mov    $0x804a180,%ecx
 8048ddd:   0f be 34 03             movsbl (%ebx,%eax,1),%esi
 8048de1:   83 e6 0f                and    $0xf,%esi
 8048de4:   03 14 b1                add    (%ecx,%esi,4),%edx
 8048de7:   83 c0 01                add    $0x1,%eax
 8048dea:   83 f8 06                cmp    $0x6,%eax
 8048ded:   75 ee                   jne    8048ddd <phase_5+0x2d>
 8048def:   83 fa 41                cmp    $0x41,%edx
 8048df2:   74 05                   je     8048df9 <phase_5+0x49>
 8048df4:   e8 98 02 00 00          call   8049091 <explode_bomb>
 8048df9:   83 c4 1c                add    $0x1c,%esp
 8048dfc:   5b                      pop    %ebx
 8048dfd:   5e                      pop    %esi
 8048dfe:   5f                      pop    %edi
 8048dff:   5d                      pop    %ebp
 8048e00:   c3                      ret   


08048f50 <string_length>:
 8048f50:   55                      push   %ebp
 8048f51:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 8048f53:   8b 55 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%edx
 8048f56:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 8048f5b:   80 3a 00                cmpb   $0x0,(%edx)
 8048f5e:   74 09                   je     8048f69 <string_length+0x19>
 8048f60:   83 c0 01                add    $0x1,%eax
 8048f63:   80 3c 02 00             cmpb   $0x0,(%edx,%eax,1)
 8048f67:   75 f7                   jne    8048f60 <string_length+0x10>
 8048f69:   5d                      pop    %ebp
 8048f6a:   c3                      ret
```

Comment: You would get more help if you told us what you've figured out so far in analyzing it yourself

Comment: *"When the program runs, it asks for user input (could be string or int). If the user enters wrong input, it will explode"* actually sounds like a pretty good summary of every assembly assignment I ever worked on... :)

Comment: 16 bytes at 0x804a180 are used as a lookup table that holds values assigned to each letter.

Answer (score 0):

The code appears(AT&T syntax is like obfuscation to my brain...) to perform a simple one-at-a-time lookup hash on the string, if the final hash is *not* 0x41, it explodes. The string is also required to be 6 characters in length, else it explodes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm such a lazy guy that I would execute **strings** on the application and try to search for something obvious there:

From: `man strings`

> strings - print the strings of printable characters in files.